# Azure Data Studio: How to save a notebook. Also, how to rename it

Tags: azure-data-studio

Just tried Azure Data Store and I really like what I see.
However, this is rediculus, I 've been around to remember the physical version of
the "3d save button" and I cannot find it here.

I have created a bunch of notebooks AzDS named `Notebook-0` through `...`. How do I save them? I can see no save option!

Also, how do I rename them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to File -> Save As
while you are in the notebook you want to save and it will allow you to save and rename your notebook.